# Windows 7 not starting

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, multi-boot

I have a dual boot machine with linux mint 18.2 (mate) and windows 7 ultimate. Currently the mint installation is working fine.

However when I try to boot into my windows partition I get a screen asking if I want to check boot or start normally.

If I select to repair the boot setup it shows a progress bar and finishes saying repairs done successfully and reboots. The windows logo shows up and animates. Next the screen goes black and a mouse appears. After about 15-20 seconds the system restarts and brings up the same screen like it did previously asking if I want to check boot or start normally. Can't get past this.

I recently did a system restore before this started happening because my windows system was randomly rebooting (sometimes with a blue screen). After the system restore the system functions properly for a while until one day it just didn't boot.

Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Yes @Gryph this setup was working previously.

Comment: The fact you had to perform a system restore is suspicious sounds like the disk is having issues, I have never in all my years of using computers, had an OS fail on me that was directly connected to the disk also failing.

Comment: @Gryph *a host of errors from UEFI and dual booting *NIX and Win* is quite a statement and a huge pile of misinformation! **And it doesn't matter anyway**: Whatever is managing the dual boot - and irrespective of installation mode, BIOS or UEFI, it's working because **both OSes boot**. Grub cannot and will not repair a defective Windows and "defective Windows" are the operational words here. Windows has problems and may need to be reinstalled, nothing to do with dual boot. It may or may not be related to a failed or failing drive but in all likelihood it is.

Comment: @Gryph Not this issue. Booting Windows only without some workarounds is typical of early UEFI implementations that violate the UEFI standards and some other quirkinesses. However, as long as you see Windows trying to boot (or Ubuntu or whatever), Grub's or UEFI bootloader's job is done and done well. Everything after that point can and does happen with Windows as a single OS. Inserting comments or considerations about the dual boot here doesn't help troubleshooting, all the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the repair steps outlined in "[Fix: The drive where Windows is installed is locked](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html)".

You need a Windows 7 installation/recovery USB to perform repair with same bit version as installed Windows 7 on disk.

1. Check and fix disk structure with chkdsk (Windows partition).
2. Fix Windows 7 boot files
3. offline sfc

You have to fix Windows 7 booting by itself and functioning first!

Then you have to reinstall GRUB!